# ActionContext.getContext() returns null using Session in Struts 2

Tags: session, struts2, struts, httpsession, actioncontext

I am trying to use `Session` in Struts 2:

```java
private Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke 
"com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.getSession()" because the return value of 
"com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.getContext()" is null
```

I tried to use `SessionMap` of Struts but still got the same error message. I have tried changing the `struts-core` libraries and also tried a few solutions from Google but still doesn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `ActionContext` is a container placeholder for the action invocation, more detailed explanation is [here](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext.html).

There's a lot of reasons when an action context could be `null`. You are starting another thread, or modify existing one, or it's just not created yet.

To get a `SessionMap` there's another approach. Let your action class to implement `SessionAware` and make sure you have configured a default interceptor stack for the action. After that the session map should be injected to the action instance. More about it [here](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/http-session.html).